# Securing Azure Web App Virtual Directory

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, web-applications, azure-active-directory

Currently I am hosting a simple web app on Azure that is secured with Azure Active Directory. This website has a virtual directory that acts as a web api to pull information from our database. The front end of the website requires you to log in, but you can bypass this by typing in the URL for the backend (virtual directory) and are still able to pull data without ever authenticating (It just sees a GET request and sends the json data). I have been trying for the past few weeks to figure out how I can ensure that you have to sign in on the front end before being able to see this information. When I try to make the backend require authentication I just get 401 unauthorized even if I send the request with the bearer token I got from authenticating on the front end.

I've tried searching for the answer, but it seems my case is a bit too specific and there isn't really any resources I've found that have been useful. If you know the proper way to achieve this or any resources you can point me to it would be a huge help! Please let me know if anything is unclear or if I should post any relevant code samples (I don't really know what would be helpful) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@rhof,

the general idea is you should config your Web API app to consume auth token that issue by AAD (from your front-end). and only accept request that carry a valid bearer token.

e.g tutorial from below link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463788.aspx